# Android MediaPlayer won't play music on API 26+

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-8.0-oreo

I have an app that streams music for the user, this code works fine ok on devices running Android up to API 25, when i test in a device running API 26 or greater the Music wont play and wont show an error message either, attached is my log when using API 28 device.

What i have tried:

- MediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(int streamtype) Deprecated so i implemented AudioAttributes for API above 26
- Different types of mp3 files, but they all play the same in api 25 and below, when i try on device or emulator with API 26 nothing happens
- Search in the docs and examples, but all look the same i see no difference in my code

  ```
  private void playMusic() {
  try {
      mMediaPlayer.reset();

      // For Android API 26 (Android 8 Oreo) and newer, specify AudioAttributes.
      if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
          Log.d("Record", "setAudioAttributes()");
          AudioAttributes.Builder builder = new AudioAttributes.Builder();
          builder.setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA);
          builder.setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC);
          AudioAttributes attributes = builder.build();
          mMediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(attributes);

      } else {
          Log.d("Record", "setAudioStreamType()");
          mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      }

      mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(String.format("http://www.server.com/mp3/%s.mp3", mp3File));
      mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
      mMediaPlayer.start();

  } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.d("Record", "error playing mp3");
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  }
  ```

Log

```
2019-04-04 17:51:38.911 2947-24864/com.roneskinder.karaoke 
V/MediaPlayer: resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
2019-04-04 17:51:38.911 2947-24864/com.roneskinder.karaoke V/MediaPlayer: cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
2019-04-04 17:51:38.913 2947-3054/com.roneskinder.karaoke D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe830ce20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe8315bd0)
2019-04-04 17:51:38.915 2947-24864/com.roneskinder.karaoke V/MediaHTTPService: MediaHTTPService(android.media.MediaHTTPService@aa03fa3): Cookies: null
2019-04-04 17:51:38.920 2947-4147/com.roneskinder.karaoke V/MediaHTTPService: makeHTTPConnection: CookieHandler (java.net.CookieManager@ead45b3) exists.
2019-04-04 17:51:38.920 2947-4147/com.roneskinder.karaoke V/MediaHTTPService: makeHTTPConnection(android.media.MediaHTTPService@aa03fa3): cookieHandler: java.net.CookieManager@ead45b3 Cookies: null
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to define a `res/xml/network_security_config.xml` and permit `HTTP` for that host:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">server.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

That `network_security_config.xml` also needs to be referenced in the `Manifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    ...>
    <application
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        ...>
            ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The SDK [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) explains it all in detail - and this applies to all network traffic an app creates.

Instead of lowering the security standards, upgrading the connection to `HTTPS` should be preferred.

---

And concerning that one deprecated method `.setAudioStreamType()`, use [.setAudioAttributes()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setAudioAttributes(android.media.AudioAttributes)) instead - as your code already does. It does not seem to be the "main problem" here; verified that.

Comment: Excellent answer, im having a similar issue loading content from a laravel server running on port 9060, i tried adding an new item like this <domain includeSubdomains="true">111.222.333.444:9060</domain> with no luck, the docs say that IPs are not allowed, so how can i proceed in this scenario?

Comment: @RonEskinder the `domain` config expects a host-name, without the port. publishing a host-name on a registered domain to [DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns/) might be the only way to get around this limitation. not that I would know of another possibility (besides using whatever public `DNS` server).

Comment: I changed the network_security_config.xml to allow all connections and it works fine now
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>`

Comment: @RonEskinder that's indeed one possibility I have not thought of, because of thinking the other way around, when it comes to `HTTP` vs. `HTTPS` (in terms of simply signing off an `SSL` certificate).

Answer (score 1):

### Just Add one line in `application` Tag

```
<application
        .......
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        .......>
        .......
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code.

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

player.setDataSource("http://www.server.com/mp3/%s.mp3");
player.setLooping(false);
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
player.prepareAsync();

player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
                    player.start();

                }

            });
```

Comment: setAudioStreamType() its deprecated for API 26+, thats the main issue im having

Comment: @RonEskinder that main issue is, that you won't even load the file.

Comment: Use setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes) instead of setAudioStreamType().