# Failed call api http in android

Tags: android, api, spring-boot, android-studio, retrofit2

i am using API localhost in android but can not call it from android. I have change localhost became IP but can not call it too. I have been using another API and it is success. I think it is because of http connection.

Comment: are you connected your phone and server in same network?

Comment: yest, solve with add config below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end i am using this [reference](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config). I also get some answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55526505/android-mediaplayer-wont-play-music-on-api-26/55575230#55575230).

You need to define a res/xml/network_security_config.xml and permit HTTP for that host:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">server.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

That network_security_config.xml also needs to be referenced in the Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    ...>
    <application
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        ...>
            ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```